# Frequency of Words in Document

Tags: functions, summation, regular-language

I'm trying to figure this out:

[image]

Would someone care to explain how one would go about using this function? More specifically, I don't understand the interval part, how does one count the intervals? Hope this is not to broad...

Comment: Might I ask why you deleted your question on Compression and Entropy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he appears to be calculating is the clustering of the uses of a word.  Say you have a book which uses a given word $1000$ times.  $x$ is the word, and then $f(x)=1000$.  Maybe all the uses are within a couple pages of each other, or maybe the uses are evenly spread through the book.  He divides the book into thousandths (the intervals) and counts how many of them include the word at least once.  If the word is evenly spread, it will be in lots of the intervals (maybe all of them) and RF(x) will approach $1000$.  If the usage is clumped, only a few intervals will include the word and RF(x) will be small.

Comment: Ok, so the intervals are calculated as the whole document divided into the times a word is found in that document?

Comment: That is correct.  $N/f(x)$ is the size of the interval, which is $1/f(x)$ times the length of the document.

Comment: So, why the whole interval function? I feel like I'm missing something... (the one after the n:th interval is:)

Comment: It is defining how you split the text up.  If the text is 2000 pages, each interval is 2 of them.  The first is pages 1 and 2, the next is pages 3 and 4, and so on.  Now you look at pages 1 and 2 and see if the word appears somewhere.  If so, Fx(1)=1, and counts into the sum RF(x)

Comment: Say your text was a 2000 page US history.  You might find that although Martin Van Buren's name appeared 1000 times, he was only mentioned within 10 pages (5 intervals) You might find that Thomas Jefferson was mentioned 5000 times, so an interval is 2/5 page, but he is mentioned in 500 of those.  You might conclude that Thomas Jefferson had a more lasting impact on US history.  The higher count might indicate that, too, but it might be more driven by other factors.  I am guessing here.